# Calculate new coordinates based on angle, when East = 0° in Java

Tags: java, coordinates

I am trying to the calculate coordinates of a new position given the angle and the distance away from current position. I think I managed to do this with the method below but using North as 0°.
But I want to the code to use:
East = 0°, North = 90°, West = 180°, South = 270°.

How can I adapt the code below to use the above orientation?

```
public double lat = 24.54;
public double lng = -2.12;
public void newPosition(double lat, double lng, int degrees, double dist) {
    double angle = Math.toRadians(degrees);

    // Calculate the change in latitude and longitude
    double delta_lat = dist * Math.cos(angle); 
    double delta_lng = dist * Math.sin(angle);
    lat += delta_lat;
    lng += delta_lng;
}
```

Comment: `degrees = degrees - 90`?

Comment: Btw. you never return any value from the method, at this point it does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the second point, I forgot to add that lat and long are class variables. As for the first point that won't work because the compass axis aren't all shifted by - 90 degrees. E, W lose 90 degrees, while N, S gain 90.